# How to reshape machine learning data to match input shape?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, model, artificial-intelligence

So I have some machine learning data split into testing and training data. The data is imported from a csv file and split into training and testing data using a numpy array.
I manage to split the data fine but when I try to use this data in the model I get an error of:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "mobilenetv2_1.00_3998" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 3998, 140, 1), found shape=(None, 140, 1)
```

I have tried to reshape the data to match the input shape of the model. This still doesn't work and not really sure how to go about doing this. The data needs to be reshaped but with the correct values.

training dataset consists of:

```
[[ 0.00770334 -1.4224063  -2.4392433  ...  2.1296244   1.7076529
   0.2145994 ]
 [-0.9572602  -2.1521447  -2.7491045  ... -3.784852   -2.7787943
  -1.727039  ]
```

testing dataset consists of:
[1. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]

shape of data:

```
x_train: (3998, 140)
x_test: (1000, 140)
y_train: (3998,)
y_test: (1000,)
```

The size of the each testing and training set:
x_train: 559720
x_test: 140000
y_train: 3998
y_test: 1000

here is my code:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2((3998, 140, 1), classes=10, weights = None)
model.compile("adam", "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

x_train = x_train.reshape(3998, 140, 1) 
x_test = x_test.reshape(1000, 140, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2` is for images only, meaning a shape of (None, Height, Width, 3), where *None* is the batch size and *3* is the number of channels. But your training data seems to have a shape of (None, 140) which does not match the required input shape. So, try to use a different model which matches your data shape, and your error will be eliminated

Comment: Do you mean as in SVM or logistic regression? if no what kind of model would be used?

Comment: Well, this depends on the data, it depends on how complex it data is. You can use a model consisted of many hidden layers with thousands of parameters or use a simple logistic regression model, try experimenting until you find the best one.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry can't comment in the question

what is the shape of your input excluding batch
is it `(3998, 140, 1)` or `(140, 1)`

if it is `(140, 1)`

i think this part should be

```
tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2((140, 1), classes=10, weights = None)
```

but if am correct mobile net input should have 3 dimension like (240, 240, 3)

[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2/MobileNetV2#args)

but the 1 data shape is (3998, 140, 1) then you should add batch dimension to it before passing to the model

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(1, 3998, 140, 1)
```